# On the Convergence of Sets

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis, analysis

Given any bounded set $E$ in $\mathbb{R}^{N}$, is there a general way to choose a sequence $(G_{n})$ of open sets such that $\chi_{G_{n}}\downarrow\chi_{E}$ pointwise?

Here $\chi$ denotes the characteristic/indicator function on $E$.

One may think of $G_{n}:=E+B(0,1/n)$, but we have instead that $\chi_{G_{n}}\downarrow\chi_{\overline{E}}$ pointwise.

So if $E$ is closed, then it follows.

**As @TheoBendit has noted in the comment box that it is what $G_{\delta}$ set is meant to be.**

So the answer is no.

Let me loose a little bit. What if I require only that $\chi_{G_{n}}\downarrow\chi_{E}$ pointwise almost everywhere?

One may think of remove the boundary $\partial E$ of the set $E$, but note that the boundary need no to be of measure zero, for example, $\partial(\mathbb{Q}\cap[0,1])=[0,1]$.

I also hope to have something like $\chi_{G_{n}}\downarrow\chi_{E}$ pointwise quasi-everywhere with respect to $\text{Cap}_{\alpha,s}$.

Here I introduce briefly the definition of $\text{Cap}_{\alpha,s}$.

For compact sets $K$, we let $\text{Cap}_{\alpha,s}(K)=\inf\{\|\varphi\|_{W^{\alpha,s}}^{s}:\varphi\geq 1~\text{on}~K\}$.

For open sets $G$, we let $\text{Cap}_{\alpha,s}(G)=\sup\{\text{Cap}_{\alpha,s}(K): K~\text{is compact in}~G\}$.

For arbitrary sets $E$, we let $\text{Cap}_{\alpha,s}(E)=\inf\{\text{Cap}_{\alpha,s}(G): G~\text{is open that contains}~E\}$.

Comment: What is the definition of $\chi_E$ here? Am I right in thinking that you want open $(G_n)$, such that $G_{n+1} \subseteq G_n$ and $E = \bigcap_n G_n$?

Comment: The characteristic/indicator function.

Comment: Okay, just made up my mind. If it were pointwise everywhere, then you meant what I meant. But I am actually looking for a.e. and q.e. cases.

Comment: I think it's worth editing to clear that up. As it stands, the answer is no, because only [$G_\delta$ sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%CE%B4_set) $E$ can be expressed in this way. I'm not versed in measure theory well enough to comment about any a.e. or q.e. cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\mu$ denote Lebesgue measure on $\Bbb R^N. $

If $E$ is $\mu$-measurable then there exists a sequence $(G_n)_n$ of open sets such that $E\subset \cap_nG_n$ and $\mu(\,(\cap_nG_n)\setminus E\,)=0.$

Let $H_n=\cap \{G_j:j\le n\}.$

If $p\in E$ then $\chi_{H_n}(p)=1=\chi_E(p)$ for all $n.$

If $p\not \in \cap_n H_n$ then $\{n:p\in H_n\}$ is finite. So for all but finitely many $n$ we have $\chi_{H_n} (p)=0=\chi_E(p).$

So if $\chi_{H_n}(p)$ does not converge to $\chi_E(p)$ then $p\in (\cap_nH_n)\setminus E, $which is a set of measure $0.$

Answer (score 0):

For arbitrary bounded set $E$, then $\text{Cap}(E)<\infty$ and hence by outer regularity, we have $G_{n}\supseteq E$ such that $\text{Cap}(E)\leq\text{Cap}(G_{n})<\text{Cap}(E)+1/n$ for each $n=1,2,...$

Then $E\subseteq\displaystyle\bigcap_{n}G_{n}$. But $\text{Cap}\left(\displaystyle\bigcap_{n}G_{n}-E\right)+\text{Cap}\left(E\right)\geq\text{Cap}\left(\displaystyle\bigcap_{n}G_{n}\right)$, so the trick by @DanielWainfleet may fail for capacity case.

Nevertheless, if $\text{Cap}(E)=0$, then it follows:

Choosing decreasing $G_{n}\supseteq E$ such that $\text{Cap}(G_{n})<1/n$, then $\text{Cap}\left(\displaystyle\bigcap_{n}G_{n}-E\right)\leq\text{Cap}\left(\displaystyle\bigcap_{n}G_{n}\right)\leq\text{Cap}(G_{n})<1/n$ for each $n=1,2,...$, so in this case, $\text{Cap}\left(\displaystyle\bigcap_{n}G_{n}-E\right)=0$.

The rest follows by the trick of @DanielWainfleet.