# On the a.e. Convergence of a Measurable Function by Simple Functions of Open Sets

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Following the previous [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3426294/on-the-a-e-convergence-of-a-measurable-function-by-simple-functions-of-compact) posted by me, an analogue question is the following:

> Suppose that $f\geq 0$ is measurable. Is there a sequence of simple functions $(s_{n})$ such that $s_{n}\downarrow f$ pointwise almost everywhere, where the simple functions $s_{n}$ are of the form
>   \begin{align*}
> s_{n}=\sum_{\text{finite sum}}a_{i}\chi_{G_{i}},
> \end{align*}
>   where $G_{i}$ is open?

Following the nice trick by @zhw. one writes
\begin{align*}
f=\sum_{n}a_{n}\chi_{A_{n}}~~~~\text{a.e.},
\end{align*}
where each $A_{n}$ is bounded measurable and $a_{n}>0$. Following the trick by @DanielWainfleet in this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3402360/on-the-convergence-of-sets), for each measurable $A_{n}$, one can find a decreasing sequence $(G_{k,n})_{k=1}^{\infty}$ of open sets such that $E\subseteq G_{k,n}$ and that $\chi_{G_{k,n}}\downarrow\chi_{A_{n}}$ a.e. as $k\rightarrow\infty$.

And again by @zhw.'s trick, one writes
\begin{align*}
\chi_{A_{n}}=\chi_{G_{1,n}}-\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}\left(\chi_{G_{k-1,n}}-\chi_{G_{k,n}}\right).
\end{align*}
Hence,
\begin{align*}
f=\sum_{n}a_{n}\left(\chi_{G_{1,n}}-\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}\left(\chi_{G_{k-1,n}}-\chi_{G_{k,n}}\right)\right),
\end{align*}
but how do we arrange the terms in the sum to achieve the goal?

Comment: @Masacroso Are you trying to say $f$ must be bounded? That's true and a good point. But otherwise I don't understand your comment.

Comment: What about $f=\displaystyle\sum_{n}n\chi_{(n,n+1)}$, this is not bounded and of course we can choose those $s_{n}$ to be $f$ itself.

Comment: Okay so how do we prove the existence of such a sequence even if $f$ is bounded?

Comment: Do you want the $a_i$ to be non-negative?

Comment: No need, that is sufficient for my purpose.

Comment: thanks for the upvote but you are right, my idea doesnt go to something... Indeed I forget completely about the open sets until you remembered it, I was just thinking in define a decreasing sequence

Comment: @user284331 On your first comment: No, you can't take $f$ itself; it's not a simple function